# Loading Sum on label

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to load the sum of txtQuantity.Text and lblPice.Text on lblPriceToBe..I'm loading my lblprice with this code.

```
private void GetData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;Integrated Security=True;");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT price,productType
                                        FROM Products3
                                        WHERE productName='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "'", connection);
    SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            lblPrice.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(); //  if price is  string use GetString(0))
            lblProdType.Text = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
    //DropDownList End of Area
}
```

After I got the price on mysql database I multiply it with txtQuantity

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
    double Price = Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice.Text);
    double sum;
    sum = Quantity * Price;
    //Output
    sum = Convert.ToDouble(lblPriceToBe.Text);
}
```

and then I get this error

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

that point on this code:

```
sum = Convert.ToDouble(lblPriceToBe.Text);
```

Comment: Have you checked what the value of "txtQuantity" is? This is probablly the reason why it fails. If you are not sure if the input value is always correct, you can also try to use `double.TryParse()`, which uses a ref value to update and returns a boolean if the parsing was successful.

Comment: @pkeuter Let me try.

Comment: @pkeuter I get this error "No overload for method 'Try Parse' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: Look at the signature of the function. You need an extra parameter, because tryparse returns a boolean. Check out the answer by @un-lucky who has given the same answer with a piece of code. That should help you out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the value in the `lblPriceToBe.Text` is not convertible to double. it may be empty or any other values which we cannot convert to double. In such particular scenarios [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to determine whether the input is convertible or not, it will also give you the converted result if the conversion is successful( else it will be 0.0); SO what you want to do is:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double Quantity,Price,sum;
    bool canProcess=true;
    if(!double.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text,out Quantity)
    {
      // conversion failed
      lblPriceToBe.Text="Invalid quantity"
      canProcess=false;
    }
    if(!double.TryParse(lblPriceToBe.Text,out Price)
    {
      // conversion failed
      lblPriceToBe.Text="Invalid Price"
      canProcess=false;
    }
    if(canProcess)
    {
    sum = Quantity * Price;
    //Output
    lblPriceToBe.Text=sum.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me an error anymore.But can I ask why the answer is not appearing on my lblPriceToBe.Text?

Comment: you need to assign the result to `lblPriceToBe.Text` see the updates

Comment: I tried the code.But the answers is still not appearing on lblPriceToBe.Text.

Comment: So the code is working fine, the input from the label is the issue, it cannot be converted as double. check that value

Comment: So I should use mysql query like the one i use on getting lblprice on my database?

Comment: It works now.I have change it to >"if(!double. TryParse(lblPrice.Text,out Price)" I replaced lblPriceToBe with lblPrice.Now it gives me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Query On your Sql/mysql Server And check that return a value , if it does try

declare those variables on the public of the class

```
public double Quantity;
public double Price;
public double Sum;
```

Then give their value by the query :

```
 Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(rdr.GetValue("columns name"));
 Price = Convert.ToDouble(rdr.GetValue("columns name"));
 Sum = Quantity * Price ;
```

Then use them in your textboxes

Comment: what happens if `rdr.GetValue("columns name")` is null?

Comment: it will shows an error but you can check that by using a condition

Comment: How many conditions you will check here? for `null` / `empty`/ `contains character` and so and so, to avoid these i have used `double.TryParse`  for the conversion

Comment: null by using if (Quantity == null  || Price  == null || Sum == null )

Comment: if the Double Variable is null (by the Query) the query return no value so the variable will be null , even if you use them, show them in textboxs , it won't return an error i just said if you want to be sure the value is not null